# Deploying portlets and modifying them without using the control panel

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-7

I'm new to Liferay Portlet development. We have an existing development pipeline that is basically local development until the code is committed and PR'd. Once a PR is approved, Jenkins builds an artifact and Puppet pushes that artifact to an instance of JBoss running in a development environment. Our deployments to QA and production environments use the same artifact.

From my (admittedly limited) understanding of Liferay administration, I know that there's a way to upload an artifact for a Portlet and then upload a new version through the Liferay control panel. Unfortunately, requiring a human to login and deploy new versions of jar files for each changed portlet won't work for our build pipeline.

What is the recommended way to deploy new versions of portlets to Liferay without having to use the UI?

Answer (score 1):

You'll just copy them to Liferay's `deploy` folder, conveniently located in Liferay's home folder.

The natural state of the deploy folder is "empty", thus you'll need appropriate permissions for Liferay on that folder, so that deployed plugins can be deleted from there.